# Cyclic Powers of Special Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

consider the number -1, i can say it is a special number because the powers of (-1) is always 1 or -1.Generally $(-1)^n = 1$ if n(mod 2) = 0 and $(-1)^n = -1$ if n(mod 2) = 1.
my question is that is there any number x such that,

- $x^n = 1$ if n(mod 3) = 0
- $x^n = 1$ if n(mod 3) = 1
- $x^n = -2$ if n(mod 3) = 2

The relation between this problem and modular arithmetic is that we can define a definite formula for n(mod k). from the approach I obtained the formula for n(mod 2) which is,

n(mod 2) = $\frac{1\space+\space(-1)^{n-1}}{2}$

the above formula comes from the sequence 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,....
this sequence starts from 0th term.In this sequence every even term is zero and every odd term is one. hence the nth term of the sequence is n(mod 2).

### Proof of the Nth Term of the Sequence

Let $S\small_ n = 0, 1, 0, 1, 0...$

$S_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i$

1.$S_n + S_{n-1}$ = 1

2.$S_n - S_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}$

Adding 1. and 2. we get,

$S_ n = \dfrac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{2}$

n(mod 2) = $S_n = \dfrac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{2}$

---

To find the formula for n(mod 3) we need to find the $n$-th term of the sequence $0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2...$

But for that we need to find x such that,

- $x^n = 1$ if n(mod 3) = 0
- $x^n = 1$ if n(mod 3) = 1
- $x^n = -2$ if n(mod 3) = 2

Then the formula for the sequence $A_n = 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2...$ will be defined as,
$$A_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i = \frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}$$

it think it would be a better information to extend my research in modular arithmetic. I am high school graduate and i didn't have any other higer mathematical knowledege than high school.

Comment: Yes: $x=a=b=c=1.$ More seriously: $x\in\Bbb C$ such that $x^3=1$ ($a=1,b=x,c=x^2$).

Comment: thanks for ur answer @Anee Bauval

Comment: Have you learned about "complex numbers", like $\sqrt{-1}$? If not, you have something to look forward to – you'll need them to make use of Anne's comment.

Comment: yea i know about complex numbers and i got the solution as x = $\frac{-1 + i\sqrt 3}{2}$, but i cant convert this into the above mentioned properties it needs.

Comment: Good. You got one solution – there are two others, namely, $x=(-1-i\sqrt3)/2$, and $x=1$. A suitable linear combination of the three solutions will give you the properties you want.

Comment: i edited my question.first i thought the general version would work i mean for any value a,b,c but i couldn't continue further. i need for specific case